# AJAX and JQuery form Subscription problems with code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm studying jQuery by myself and I'm still working on my own code for the Mailchimp Opt-In form. I know there are other questions about this already asked, but I want to understand why my own code isn't working as a nooby jQuery student. I don't want to copy others' code, I just want to make my code working.

I already put the **post-json?u=** and the **&c=?** in the action.
So, this is my html code: (Just look at the divs with comments)

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form action="https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/subscribe/post-json?u=xxxxxx;id=xxxxx&c=?" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>


                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

                    <div id="colonna-sx">

                        <div class="mc-field-group gruppo-email">                       
                            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">

<!-- THIS ONE -->
                            <div id="obbligo-email" class="obbligo-form" style="color:red">Campo obbligatorio</div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="mc-field-group gruppo-nome">                        
                            <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">

<!-- THIS ONE -->
                            <div id="obbligo-nome" class="obbligo-form" style="color:red">Campo obbligatorio</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                        <div class="mc-field-group input-group gruppo-consenso">
                            <input type="radio" value="Acconsento al trattamento dei miei dati personali." name="CONSENSO" id="mce-CONSENSO-0"><label for="mce-CONSENSO-0">Acconsento al trattamento dei miei dati personali.</label>

<!-- THIS ONE -->
                            <div id="obbligo-consenso" class="obbligo-form" style="color:red">Campo obbligatorio</div>
                        </div>


                        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_6a6f3b7082472f64c07c2cad3_e065e0e3c4" tabindex="-1" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div id="colonna-dx">
                        <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="mc-button"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

As you can see, I have some "divs" with the comment "THIS ONE" and ids #obbligo-email, #obbligo-nome and #obbligo-consenso, **with "display: none" on my css file**. So I want this 3 error messages appear or disappear if the input fields are empty or not.

So this is my jQuery code

```
(function($) {
       var $form = $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form");
       var stato1;
       var stato2;
       var stato3;

       $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").bind("click", function(event){
              if (event) event.preventDefault();
              if ($("#mce-EMAIL").val()!=""){
                     $("#obbligo-email").css({"display":"none"});
                     stato1=true;
              } else {
                     $("#obbligo-email").css({"display":"block"});
                     stato1=false;
              },

              if ($("#mce-FNAME").val()!=""){
                     $("#obbligo-nome").css({"display":"none"});
                     stato2=true;
              } else {
                     $("#obbligo-nome").css({"display":"block"});
                     stato2=false;
              },

              if ($("#mce-CONSENSO-0").is("=checked")){
                     $("#obbligo-consenso").css({"display":"none"});
                     stato3=true;
              } else {
                     $("#obbligo-consenso").css({"display":"block"});
                     stato3=false;
              },

              if (stato1==true && stato2==true && stato3==true) {
                     register($form);
              }

       });

       function register($form) {
              $.ajax({
                     type: $form.attr('method'),
                     url: $form.attr('action'),
                     data: $form.serialize(),
                     cache: false,
                     dataType: 'json',
                     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              })
       };

}(jQuery));
```

I tried to understand other answers sent on StackOverFlow with no results, so I'm here to see if someone can help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

In my mind, I want the 3 error messages to be displayed when the input fields are empty, and 3 boolean variables to be true if everything is ok.

If the 3 boolean variables are true, so send the form with Ajax, and I don't want to reload the page, just clear the input fields.

**Some informations I don't understand:**

PS: If I change the "method" to "get", I have a 404 error page.

PSS: If I use "$(document).ready( funtion(){" the javascript file doesn't work (i tried with an alert to know it, but I don't know why).

Comment: check the javascript console of your browser's dev tools (f12) you should be seeing syntax error messages as you have commas (`,`) in places you shouldnt

Comment: Also [serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/#serialize) produces a name value pair query string (eg `k=v&v=k`) and not json which is what you set the outgoing content type to `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: Hi, I changed those commas but still doesn't work

Comment: Hi @PatrickEvans, so what have I to use there? I see others code using that (and the form was working fine), so that's why I wrote that :(

Comment: If there is nothing in the console then your code isnt being run at all. Are you correctly including your script into the page.

Comment: Yes, If i put an Alert after the variables, it shows up

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery code you have some sematic syntax error. You end your if/else with a comma... It is wrong. When you end your if/else you should use only curly braces {}  without any comma after braces.

Also you have a wrong check in jQuery:

```
if ($("#mce-CONSENSO-0").is("=checked"))
```

you should use `:checked`. Not `=checked`. So you should write like this:

```
if ($("#mce-CONSENSO-0").is(":checked"))
```

I can try to answer you on your PS question:

PS:
As I can see you make a POST request to some external API endpoint `https://xxxxxxxxxx.com/subscribe/post-json[...]`. As we can see here maybe this endpoint handle only POST requests no GET requests so you get 404 error (The server can not find requested resource.). More about status codes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404

Comment: Hi and thank you for the answer! Btw, I see others code with the get request, so that's why I don't understand that

Answer (score 0):

also remove the comma on the last key/value of your Json object

```
              $.ajax({
                 type: $form.attr('method'),
                 url: $form.attr('action'),
                 data: $form.serialize(),
                 cache: false,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          })
```

Remove the comma on this line

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

**Here is a sample of the code:**

```js
            $(function(){

                $("[type=submit]").on("click", function(e){

                    // ---Prevent the form from submiting

                    e.preventDefault();

                    let errorFound = false;


                    // --- Check if fields are empty, if so show an exclamation mark icon

                    if($("[type=text]").val() == ""){
                        $("[type=text]").css("background", "url('exclamation-outline.svg') no-repeat right");
                        errorFound = true;
                    }
                    
                    if($("[type=text]").val() == ""){
                        $("[type=text]").css("background", "url('exclamation-outline.svg') no-repeat right");
                        errorFound = true;
                    }
                    

                    // --- Process form
                    if(errorFound == false)
                    register($("form"));

                });




                function register($form) {

                    

                    $.ajax({
                        
                            type: $form.attr('method'),
                            url: $form.attr('action'),
                            data: $form.serialize(),
                            cache: false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

                    });

                };



            });
```

```css
            * { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; }
            ul{ list-style: none; }
            body, html { height: 100vh;  }
            input{ outline: none; border: none; background: none;  }
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{ font-weight: normal; }
            p, li, a, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{ user-select: none; } 
            body{ display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }
            input{ height: 48px; display: block; width: 320px; margin-bottom: 24px; }
            input:not([type=submit]){ border-bottom: 1px dashed grey;  }
            input[type=submit]{ background: grey; border-radius: 4px; cursor: pointer; color: white; }
```

```html
        <form action="?user=login" method="POST" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="password" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
```